# How to click a button without name, id, or value?

Tags: javascript

Here is the button code :

```
<button class="btn btn-close btn-join btn-info btn-large">Join</button>
```

This button is inside a popup modal dialog, how could I use java-script to click on this button?

Comment: do you want trigger click & is this code created dynamically ?

Comment: If the button is the only one in the modal, you can reference the modal and select the button relatively to the modal. No?

Comment: The code is from this website : http://sync-video.com/r/rjk7GIFa

I am trying to change the content of the textbox and then click the "JOIN" button. At the same time, I am trying to remove the "LEAVE" button from the modal window as well. I am trying to use javascript to accomplish this.

Comment: @David So Please choose right tag for any question (As you have chosen wrong tag in your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

Select by element.

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").click();
```

Select by class.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").click(); //or .btn-close, or btn-join, etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class or id on the parent modal itself, you could target the button with:

```
$("#your-modal .btn-close").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only button in your jquery-ui modal window. you could do it like this:

```
$('.ui-dialog button').click();
```

If there is more than one button, you can access it by adding the class of any other wrapper that might only encompass this button.

```
$('.ui-dialog .some-class button').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

ever best way

```
$('button.btn-join').click()
```